# What determines the appended string when we sign a msix application with signtool

Tags: code-signing-certificate, signtool, msix

I bought a code signing certificate last year and signed a msix package using the sign tool

`sign /f` "$SigningKeyFilePath`" /fd SHA256 /v /a /p $SigningKeyPassword "$Package"`

The resultant msix package when installed created a folder in AppData directory with the name PackageName_244zpcd23egta, since the certificate was valid only for a year, we had to get a new certificate, we were told that we can't renew the existing.

Now after signing with the new certificate the folder created is different `PackageName_123zwerd23ewea`, this means that we can't update the previously installed application. MSIX installer returns error say a previous application with same name is already installed.

I want to know how can we prevent this problem in future? What determines the _randowm_looking_number at the end of folder? I have noticed the new certificate did not had the pin code. Could that make this happen? or that we should always insist on certificate renewal (if it is possible) and not get a new certificate?

Answer (score 2):

The block appended at the end of the string is a publisher hash, calculated from your subject (publisher). It is a 13-character string, base32-encoded representation of first few bytes of SHA-256 hash of your certificate Distinguished Name.

The algorithm is relatively straightforward:

1. Take UTF-16 string containing the publisher name (certificate DN) (as-is, with all spaces and punctuations)
2. Calculate SHA-256 hash of byte representation of this string
3. Take first 8 bytes (64 bits)
4. Pad the binary value by a single zero bit to the right (= left shift all bits)
5. Group the bits in groups of 5 (since we had 64 + 1 bits, we should get 13 groups each having 5 bytes)
6. For each group, convert the bit representation to an integer, and perform a look-up in a replacement table mapping the numbers to letters and digits.
7. Join the letters together and make them lowercase to receive the publisher hash.

This can be done for example via the following PowerShell

```
function Get-PublisherHash($publisherName)
{
    $publisherNameAsUnicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($publisherName);
    $publisherSha256 = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create("SHA256").ComputeHash($publisherNameAsUnicode);
    $publisherSha256First8Bytes = $publisherSha256 | Select-Object -First 8;
    $publisherSha256AsBinary = $publisherSha256First8Bytes | ForEach-Object { [System.Convert]::ToString($_, 2).PadLeft(8, '0') };
    $asBinaryStringWithPadding = [System.String]::Concat($publisherSha256AsBinary).PadRight(65, '0');
 
    $encodingTable = "0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
 
    $result = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $asBinaryStringWithPadding.Length; $i += 5)
    {
        $asIndex = [System.Convert]::ToInt32($asBinaryStringWithPadding.Substring($i, 5), 2);
        $result += $encodingTable[$asIndex];
    }
 
    return $result.ToLower();
}
```

For example:

```
Get-PublisherHash "CN=SomeName, DN=Some Domain"
> qwz5zh2hhehvm
```

Any change of your certificate (where the publisher name changes) means that the  hash is completely different. And since the hash is a part of MSIX family name and its full package name, the new app is treated as another application.

In some recent efforts to change it (Insider Builds 22000 and newer) there is a feature called "Persistent identity", which can be used to provide a smooth upgrade experience even if the certificate changes.

Source:

- [My blog post about calculating the hash](https://marcinotorowski.com/2021/12/19/calculating-hash-part-of-msix-package-family-name/)
- [Microsoft documentation for feature "Persistent identity"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/persistent-identity)
- [Description of base32 algorithm](http://www.crockford.com/base32.html)